# Jinja List Issue

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

I am getting a weird problem in Jinja, I have a list `endpoints`, which contains dictionary for every `endpoint`. In each dictionary, there is a key `tags` which is a list. Every item in `tags` is itself a dictionary where the key `value` gives the label of a tag. `endpoint` may have similar tags.

A sample abstract representation of an `endpoints` object can be:

```
[ {"tags":[{"value":"car"},{"value":"place"}]} , {"tags":[{"value":"van"},{"value":"place"}]} ]
```

what I want is to simple display unique tags in a div. It is simple, keeping a list of all displayed tags and upon getting a tag, checking if it is already in the list, and if not display it and add it to the list. Weirdly, it's not working.

The codes are:

```
{% set tagValues = [] %}
{% for endpoint in endpoints %} 
        {% for tag in endpoint["tags"]%}
                {% set tagValue = tag["tag"]["value"] %}
                {% if tagValue not in tagValues %} 
                        {% set tagValues = tagValues  + [tagValue]  %}
                        <span >{{ tagValue }}</span></a>
                {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

it is not working, for example, for the enpoints list above, I am getting the following output:

```
car place van place
```

is there any problem with the codes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating a distinct list of tags in your View. e.g.

```
distinctTags = list(set([tag for endpoint in endpoints for tag in endpoint]))
```

and passing that to your template

```
{% for tag in distinctTags %} 
    <span >{{ tagValue }}</span></a>
{% endfor %}
```

this has the advantage of the distinct tag code being reusable and the code being less procedural.

Answer (score 1):

my jinja knowledge is limited, but by adding `tagValues` to the output, it appears that it's reset after each iteration of the outer loop. I'd guess it's to do with scopes, but don't know.

My recommendation would be to pre-process your `endpoints` in regular python before passing to jinja

Comment: yes, that is what happening, it is resetting the tag values